# Not receiving device's Intent Action in Android Xamarin.Forms app's BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, barcode-scanner

I have an Android barcode scanner device (Urovo DT50) and I'm trying to create an app, with Xamarin.Forms in VS 2022, to receive and process the scanned value.

The device's Scanner Settings indicate it will send an Intent Action of android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA.  So, I created a simple BarcodeScannerReceiver class...

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class BarcodeScanReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string value = intent.GetStringExtra("key");
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this class would get registered to receive the action, but I can't get it reach a debugging breakpoint.  Am I missing an important step, or am I way off base for what I think should be happening?

I've read that the AndroidManifest.xml file should get automatically updated to reflect the BroadcastReceiver, but I don't see anything to reflect this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.xamarinforms1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="XamarinForms1.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks for any suggestions on how to receive the device's Intent Action.

Comment: **1)** Haven't told Android what **intent** your app receives. Add `IntentFilter` Attribute, as described in [Broadcast Receivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers). **2)** I'm not sure if it gets automatically added to **that** copy of AndroidManifest.xml. If not, after Build, use Windows Explorer to search for `AndroidManifest.xml` file under a subfolder of `YourProject.Android/obj/`. This file is the final one added to the Android bundle/apk.

Comment: in my experience most devices like these can be configured as keyboard wedges, where they just direct their input to whatever UI element has focus on the device